# After pd.read_csv(filename) my row-numbers are NaN, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Picture of my DataFrame and theh error log when I try to access any values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHRkC.jpg)

I have been working on sample logs that contain certain numbers that I require. For most csv files that I create the row numbers are created and I can access values that I need from my data frame. However, for this particular file, after the csv file is created and I do pd.read_csv(*filename*) all the row numbers are NaN (attached a picture for reference).
Anyone know why/how I could possibly fix this or direct me to a resource that could help?

(PS: Image shows my dataframe with the NaN row-numbers and the error log when I try to access values from any row. I understand that it is because my row numbers are NaN)

Thanks!

EDIT 1: The code snippet where I am using pd.read_csv, printing the dataframe and trying to access value of row 0, column 1

```
ufo = pd.read_csv(output_file, skiprows=2, usecols=range(1, 7))
print(ufo)
print (ufo.loc[0, ufo.columns[1]])
```

Comment: Can you add more of your code to help provide a more complete picture?

Comment: first open csv file in normal text editor to see what you have in file. Maybe it is not problem with row-numbers but maybe you have `NaN` as text in rows. Or maybe you have `NaN` as row-numbers in this file.

Comment: @furas I have tried to do that. The NaN is definitely for row numbers. My code works perfectly fine for other similar files but it is making an error for this one.